# How can I define keybinds for the buy-screen?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I'd like to define keys for frequently used items on the buy-screen, like kevlar, helm, M4A1, AK47, Deagle, etc.

On CS:S and CS1.6 I could define those only by manually editing some configuration file.

How can I accomplish that on CS:GO?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do as in CSS. Just put everything in config.cfg.
bind "*keyname*" "buy *weaponname*"

Comment: Or `autoexec.cfg`. For weapon key names, for example see: http://csgobuynds.com/